# gitignore doesn't ignore .suo Visual studio file

Tags: git, github

I want to do simple thing, ignore .suo file and bin and obj folders from committing to git repo. I've created .gitignore file and it's working for bin and obj folders, but it keeps allowing .suo file committing. 
The content of gitignore is simple:

```
/build/
*.suo
*.user
_ReSharper.*/
*.sdf
bin/
obj/
Debug/
Release/
*.opensdf
*.tlog
*.log
TestResult.xml
*.VisualState.xml
Version.cs
Version.h
Version.cpp
```

Firstly I've thought that the problem is that .suo file is already on the repo, so I've used set of git commands to remove it from repo:

```
git rm "file.suo"
git commit -m "suo removed"
git pull origin master
git push origin master
```

And everything goes well, .suo is removed locally, it is removed from repo, and on the next commit it gets pushed again to repo.

On the picture is committed .suo file.

[image]

Did anyone had a problem like this? How to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Did  you pay attention to what `git status` tells you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [gitignore all files of extension in directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712555/gitignore-all-files-of-extension-in-directory)

Comment: It looks like you want to use the _**/*.suo_ pattern to ignore files like this in all directories. The pattern you have used only applies to the project root.

Comment: "*on the next commit it gets pushed*" No. Firstly, nothing gets pushed when you commit. Secondly, nothing gets commited unless it has been explicitly added.

Comment: @nwinkler No this syntax is supposed to ignore all files anywhere in the tree matching that pattern.

Comment: @nwinkler what is the best place to put .gitignore? Should it be in git folder or somewhere else?

Comment: You can add `.gitignore` files anywhere in your repo. Either in the root, and use patterns like I mentioned above, or in each individual directory in your repo. You can also use both - one in the root for general exclusions, and then individual ones per directory. Make sure you add and commit the `.gitignore` files as well.

Comment: Place the `.gitignore` in the directory that **contains** the `.git` directory in order to apply it to all your sources below that path. Use https://www.gitignore.io to create a `.gitignore`.

Comment: The following answer might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11629271/4371525

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GIT - Can't ignore .suo file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628418/git-cant-ignore-suo-file)

Answer (score 59):

This is probably a duplicate of [GIT - Can't ignore .suo file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628418/git-cant-ignore-suo-file/11629271#11629271)

And to be honest, you can try that suggestion. What you are missing here is to remove the already added `*.suo` file from the git repository.

The other answer has a nice set of commands to run:

```
git rm --cached *.suo
git commit -m "Delete suo file from repository"
```

Answer (score 1):

Jsper answered correct. He already explained why this usually happens. But I got another probably easy solution without command line & gui lover devs. What I simply do is:

1. First delete the directory or file from your github/dev ops repository from web gui
2. Then simply sync your project locally first then you are ready to make new commit without your annoying autogenerated file or directory.